# Как спарсить строку?

Tags: c++, строки

Есть строка вида: `"40 1234567 12"`

Нужно спарсить вторую по счету строчку (то есть: 1234567)

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: все защиты от дурака отключены, считаем, что формат именно такой, как показано.

Например: :)

```
string s =  "40 1234567 12", get;
istringstream in(s);
s >> get;
s >> get;
```

Или:

```
s = s.substr(s.find(' ')+1);
s = s.substr(0,s.find(' '));
```

Comment: только, учитывая, что после первого слова вполне может быть не один пробел,  убрать   +1 и добавить   получение строки с первого непробела:   s = s.substr(s.find_first_not_of(' '));

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Повторюсь: "*Disclaimer: все защиты от дурака отключены, считаем, что* **формат именно такой, как показано.**" А показан один пробел...

Comment: Harry, я вижу, только выдал информацию для  Skymotion

Answer (score 1):

Если надо не только второе слово вывести то можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s); // вводим строку
    istringstream iss(s);

    // записываем все слова в вектор
    vector <string> a { istream_iterator<string>{iss}, 
                        istream_iterator<string>{} };


    cout << a[1] << endl; // выводим второе слово
    return 0;
}
```