# Не могу корректно записать строку слов C++

Tags: c++, строки, ввод

Сделана в принципе вся программа но я не могу сделать ввод слов из клавиатуры.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale (0, "");
char stroka[] = {""};
cout << "blalala \n --->";
cin >> *stroka ;
int n = sizeof(stroka) / sizeof(stroka[0]);
for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
cout << stroka[i];
/*for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0;j < 6;j++) 
    {

        if (str[i][j] == 'a' && str[i][j + 1] == 'b' && str[i][j + 2] == 'c') 
        {
            str[i][j] = 'd';
            str[i][j + 1] = 'e';
            str[i][j + 2] = 'f';
        }

        cout << str[i][j] << " - str[" << i << "][" << j << "]" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

*/
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите сюда на мой ответ, думаю будёт все понятно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь cделать ввод через String

```
include <string>
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(0, "");
        string str;
        std::cout << "blalala \n --->";
        getline(cin,str);

        cout << str << endl;


        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char stroka[] = {""};
```

Т.е. `stroka` - массив из 1 элемента `char`.

```
cin >> *stroka;
```

Считали 1 (прописью: *один*) символ.

```
int n = sizeof(stroka) / sizeof(stroka[0]);
```

`n` равно 1. Дальше этот считанный символ выводится в цикле из одной итерации.

Что попрошено, то и сделано. Чтобы посоветовать вам, что делать - нужно ясное ТЗ, что именно вы хотите. Ваше же описание сугубо негативное (*"не могу ..."*).